# Use fill from tidyr in both directions 'up' and 'down'

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to use `fill` from tidyr to replace NAs in **both** directions.

The help informations says:

> fill(data, ..., .direction = c("down", "up"))

Actually, it would be nice to use exactly this format of direction. But it does not work, as it brings an error:

> Error: Unknown column `down`

I know the info says:

> Direction in which to fill missing values. Currently either "down"
>   (the default) or "up".

I understand the meaning of 'or'. But if I want to use both directions, do i really need to make two steps?

Here is an example:

```
ID <- rep(1,3)
Sess <- c(1,2,3)

df1 <- data.frame(ID,Sess)

Sess <- 2
code <- 55
df2 <- data.frame(Sess, code)

df <- left_join(df1,df2)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% fill(code) %>% fill(code, .direction =  'up')
```

I was thinking about something like: `fill(code, .direction = 'both')`

Comment: It's not clear what the result is even supposed to look like with both "down" and "up". Please provide an example.

Comment: Not sure whether this is a duplicate because i am asking for both directions. The other solutions also use a second step by rearranging the data to put the value at the last position. Or did i miss something?